# Explaining what this command does

Tags: linux, command-line, ls, wildcards, lp

`ls *.txt | lp`

Wouldn't this command list all files that end in .txt and then print them?

Comment: Do you want to print the file listing or the contents of the files?

Comment: OP follow up Q: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/646885/4667

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is "No".

`lp` takes either a [list of] files, or `STDIN`. The command as offered does nothing except fire up an empty print job:

```
$ ls *.txt|lp
request id is queue-153 (0 file(s))
```

It's not clear what you wanted. If you want to print a list of files matched by the glob `*.txt`, then you need to tell `lp` to use `STDIN`:

```
$ ls *.txt|lp -
```

If you want to print the *content* of the files matched by the glob `*.txt`, then you would simply pass the glob itself to `lp`:

```
$ lp *.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure? Wouldn't `ls *.txt | lp` produce a single output consisting of a list of the file names?

Comment: No, it does not. I tried it. `lp` doesn't take `STDIN` _unless you tell it_ with `lp -`

Comment: That shows how long it is since I used `lp` :-) The ancient [Printing HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Printing-HOWTO/how.html#AEN120) also says, "_To specify a queue you use the -d option and a filename to print a file, or nothing to print from stdin_"

Comment: I know - like, "who uses printers these days?!" lol - I thought I'd pick it up since where I work, we actually do.

Comment: I do print quite a lot, but mostly through Windows 10. Happy to delete the comment thread to clean up

Comment: No, leave it! The link to the Printing HOWTO is illuminating history. This is the "Linux & **Unix**" SE, so the historical perspective is useful.

Answer (score -2):

The `lp` command requires the files to be given as command-line arguments, not via stdin.

If you are trying to print the files (and not to print the list of file names), `ls` is completely unneeded:

```bsh
lp *.txt
```

Comment: Hang on, I haven't used `lp` in years, but that seems like it would print the contents of the files while the OP's command would cause `lp` to print the list of file names. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Can we just say RTFM? `man lp`.

Comment: @waltinator no, no we can't say that without being both needlessly rude and offensive, and coming across as kind of pretentious. Sure, Glenn is wrong here, but that happens to the best of us and there's no reason to be rude about it. All you need to do is downvote and walk away.

Comment: @waltinator, no, not without saying what you're trying to tell can be found there. In most cases, chances are the person you're going to say that to has already read the fine manual, but hasn't for some reason found the right section or noticed the correct passage. Just telling them to RTFM again doesn't help in fixing that, and since you already know what to look for, you might as well tell it.

Comment: I'd argue that I'm not wrong: the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Totally agree, Glenn. I'm not looking to "win", but you did say "not via stdin" which ain't true :-)  I had to make guesses with my answer.

Comment: @terdon SysV.3 allowed `lp` to read from _stdin_, but the SVR4 and CUPS reimplementations of `lp` on top of `lpr` do not. (No, I didn't know either.)

Comment: A POSIX-conforming `lp` takes data from STDIN. Nowadays `lp` is very likely to be from CUPS which apparently bizarrely doesn't work this way.

Comment: Ha! You're quite right Glenn, it is indeed ambiguous. I understood "list all files and then print them" to mean print the list of files, but it could just as well be read as printing the files themselves. And thanks, @roaima, I think I haven't used `lp` in the last 15 years.