# Difference between commands

Tags: linux, command-line

> ls *.txt | lp

I was told that this command above wouldn't do anything but start an empty print queue

if so then wouldn't the command

> cat *.txt | lp

print all files that end in .txt right?

Answer (score 1):

From the `lp` manpage.

> DESCRIPTION lp submits files for printing or alters a pending job. Use a filename of "-" to force printing from the standard input.

So depending on your print system you might get different results from

```bsh
lp *.txt
```

vs

```bsh
cat *.txt | lp -
```

The former lp looks at each file individually (and knows the name for it).  In the latter the output of all those files is made into one and then lp treats it as one unnamed file.

Some print systems do a cover page per thing submitted - so you can see how it might be different with "N" things vs 1.

Comment: i agree with this, i think ls *.txt | lp lists and prints the files one by one and cat *.txt | lp prints all the files as one unnamed file

Answer (score -1):

`ls *.txt` and `cat *.txt` is not the same at all.

`ls *.txt` will list all the files in the current directory with the extension ".txt".

while `cat *.txt` try to find a file "*.txt" from the current directory and print the file content on standard output.

Solution:

```
ls *.txt > ouput_file
lp output_file
```

Comment: so ls *.txt | lp would try to list all files that end in .txt and print them while cat *.txt | lp would look for a file named ".txt" from current directory and try to print it

Comment: @OneEyedOwl `ls *.txt | lp` will print, one file per line all **filename** ending in txt, while `cat *.txt|lp` will print all file **content** in alphabetical order.

Comment: Hi @OneEyedOwl - `ls *.txt` is giving output matching the names of the files (i.e. think of it as a file with the names of all the files in it).  The man page for lp on my machine doesn't mention that supplying a list of names on stdin will print each of them - perhaps yours does??

Comment: @Archemar why you marked my answer "-1"??

Comment: Someone give you a "-1" but I didn't, I just review you post in review queue and add the comment above.